# Best approach to maven project-specific scripts?

Tags: java, maven

In `npm` we have the option to define project specific scripts in the `package.json` file as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts).

What is the best tool/approach to this with maven? I'd like a way to write cross-platform, reproducible scripts with minimal setup.

Example scripts and the raw commands:

- Build the project into a JAR file, skipping tests, and then deploy as part of a docker-compose deployment

  - `mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
  - `docker-compose up --build -d`
- Rebuild and replace the running container in the docker-compose deployment

  - `mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
  - `docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build spring`
- Build the project and run tests without deploying

  - `mvn clean install`

These commands can be a pain to remember and this is a project that will be used by many students with limited maven and docker experience. So a tool that's easy to install and makes creating scripts that 'just work' when pulling the repository would be great.

Comment: Add the correct plugins, define profiles and _just use Maven_!!

Comment: Off topic: are those `npm` scripts really cross platform?

Comment: @tgdavies It depends on what scripts you create, but as long as you're only using node modules as part of your scripts then yes. It is easy to run any script by writing `npm install` then `npm run <script_name>`